# Sequelize Update HasMany Relationships

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I would like to update the rows of a hasMany relation, I have a table InRoutes that can have many InRouteDetails, so when I update InRoute I also need to update it details, there are three cases that can happen, delete an detail, update an detail and add an detail.

When I try to update using setInRouteDetails but for some reason he tries to get an InRouteDetail that is equal an object given me this error: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '[object Object]'

This is my model:

```js
export default (sequelize, DataType) => {
  const InRoutes = sequelize.define('InRoutes', {
    id: {
      type: DataType.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataType.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: true,
      },
    },
    description: {
      type: DataType.TEXT,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    createdBy: {
      type: DataType.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    updatedBy: {
      type: DataType.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: (models) => {
        InRoutes.hasMany(models.InRoutesDetails, {
          foreignKey: 'InRouteId',
          as: 'InRouteDetails',
          onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        });
        InRoutes.belongsTo(models.Trunks, {
          foreignKey: 'trunkId',
          as: 'TrunkId',
          onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        });
      },
    },
  });

  return InRoutes;
};
```

This is where I try do update "InRoute" with his association "InRouteDetails":

```js
  async update(data, params, updatedBy) {
    data.updatedBy = updatedBy.username;

    try {
      const inRoute = await this.InRoutes.findOne({ where: params });

      const teste = [{
        id: 2,
        mask: '89',
        remove: 4,
        add: '3',
        destinationType: 'callback',
        destination: 2,
        InRouteId: 2,        
      }];
      
      await inRoute.addInRouteDetails(teste);
      await inRoute.update(data);      

      return defaultResponse(inRoute);
    } catch (error) {
      return errorResponse(error.message, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
    }
  }
```

This gives me this result on console:

```js
Executing (default): UPDATE `InRoutesDetails` SET `InRouteId`=?,`updatedAt`=? WHERE `id` IN ('[object Object]')
```

He tries to compare id with some object.

Comment: Please provide the query that you have tried. Sample table structure, data, expected output would be nice.

Comment: Sorry @sicKo I updated my question providing more details and my code, thank's for the reply.